# Add widgets on event . Kivy

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer

I try to add Button on event and there is no results.This is part of code where I call 'add_picture' function.What is a problem?

**UPD**
Build method makes gui interface by .kv file.

```
class TakePictureApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.index = 0
        activity.bind(on_activity_result=self.on_activity_result)

    def on_activity_result(self, requestCode, resultCode, intent):
        if requestCode == 0x123:
            Clock.schedule_once(partial(self.add_picture, self.last_fn), 0)
```

In this place try to add Button(2 methods)

```
    def add_picture(self, fn, *args):
        self.Button.text = 'Allo'

        # return Button(text = 'Allo')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your build method should return widget tree. For example I could use it in the way that my `build()` returns `Label`, and I add `widgets` to that `Label`.
Your `build()` method looks like it doesn't return anything..

Comment: For build tree I use .kv file. Do I understand correctly, after build method I can't add widgets??

Comment: No. You can add wigdets, but you can add them only to the widget that you return in build() method. Look at the code in this tutorial (scroll down to final code): https://kivy.org/docs/tutorials/firstwidget.html . Build method returns parent object. And you should add your widgets to that parent object. Build method MUST return something.